# Dynamics CRM Power Apps Web Portal Form and Its Subgrid did not show in the web browser

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-portals, powerapps-portal

I am preparing a Power Apps web portal. But when I am adding a Form on my page and testing on browser, subgrid is not showing.

Preview on Web browser image which does not show Subgrid:

[image]

This is my developing screen where I'm adding a Web Form:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because the form in **Insert** mode, try changing it to **Edit** mode to see the subgrid. You cannot add child records in subgrid unless parent entity record is saved/created/inserted, that is the reason.

> When creating a new entity form, the first step is to decide the Entity and Form Name that you will be rendering, in addition to the mode: Insert, Edit, or Read Only. The mode selected will determine if you are creating a new record from the portal, editing an existing record, or just displaying information about a record on the portal.

[Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/portals/configure/entity-forms#add-a-form-to-your-portal)

Comment: You are right but I want to create Business Unit and existing record from sub grid from the web portal. like CRM form create mode. So is that any best way to create that into the web portal?

Comment: @NihalBhatasna sorry, I didn’t get you.

Comment: I need to create a web for into power apps (form as well as Grid) so is that any option to create that?

Comment: The record needs to be created before you can add associated records